# Change the state key dynamically in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

Is there any possibility to have a dynamic state for every terraform entity?  I mean the key.  Is a bit weird to change manually the key for every entity.

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "terraform-dev"
    encrypt        = true
    key            = "???"
    dynamodb_table = "???"
    region         = "eu-west-1"
    profile        = "dev"
  }
}
```

Comment: Currently Terraform can't dynamically create or change existing resources. Whole concept is that resource have to be created (or important) and state of it is stored. This is how differences for possible changes can be evaluated.

You can define a map with list of resources and use `for_each` to iterate over it, take a look at the [example](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/for-each)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to set a different key for every resource. The key for the `s3` backend is where the state is stored for your entire Terraform definition; it is exactly the same as the `terraform.tfstate` file that is stored to your local directory when you run Terraform without using remote state (e.g. `s3`). In that case, you have a whole tree of resources, but their states are all stored into the one `terraform.tfstate` file; when you use the `s3` remote state backend, the states for your whole tree of resources are stored in the one object in `s3`, at the key provided in that `backend` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by creating a separate backend.conf file. But will not be able to configure the S3's key dynamically in the main.tf itself.

I could achieve this by creating a backend.tf dynamically (in the pipeline) before executing terraform init, with a shell command like below. Make sure this file is created in the right path from where you want to do the terraform init.

```
cat <<EOF > backend.conf
bucket            = "bucket-name"
key               ="${platform_name}/${stack_name}/state.tfstate"
encrypt           = "true"
region            = "eu-west-1"
dynamodb_table = "${table-name}-lock-table"
EOF
```

And then you can do

```
terraform init  -backend-config backend.conf
```

This worked well for me